# Views Slideshow Carousel

Tags: views, javascript

Is there a way in Views Slideshow to make the pager to follow the slide? Here is the link of the sample slider that I require http://www.jssor.com/demos/content-slider.html
When you clicked the next/prev button, then the thumbnail follows with the main slider.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How come it's off-topic if I was implementing my requirements using views slideshow? The link I've provided is only for reference. I don't understand.

Comment: You show no own effort. You just posted your requirements and want people do things for you. No matter if link is only for reference - "only description" questions are clearly forbidden, too. Tell us what have you tried and what stopped you from finishing, at the very least.